# Write the following as a fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

$1+\dfrac{1}{6x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2+3x}$

I keep getting answer like $\dfrac{6x^2 + 19x + 9}{6x(x+3)}$ but I think
it's wrong because I get different answers. Please help me

Greetings from Russia!

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! I obtain the same result

Comment: You did it right.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
1 + \frac{1}{6x} + \frac{1}{x^2+3x} &= 1 + \frac{1}{6 x} + \frac{1}{x(x+3)} \\
&= 1 + \frac{x + 3}{6x(x+3)} + \frac{6}{6x(x+3)} = 1 + \frac{x + 9}{6x(x+3)} \\
&= \frac{6x^2 + 19x + 9}{6x(x+3)}
\end{align}